# for loop to join columns and then sort in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, sorting, addition

I need to use a for loop that can add column 1 to column 3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17
and sort column 2,4,6,8,10,12.14,16,18

I tried to use for but am having difficulties in applying it

```
first_column<- c("^","G","A","T","T","A","C","A")
second_column<- sort(first_column)
third_column<-paste(first_column,second_column)

fourth_column<-sort(third_column)
fifth_column<-paste(first_column,fourth_column)

sixth_column<-sort(fifth_column)
seventh_column<-paste(first_column,sixth_column)

eight_column<-sort(seventh_column)
ninth_coulmn<-paste(first_column,eight_column)

tenth_coulmn<-sort(ninth_coulmn)
elventh_coulmn<-paste(first_column,tenth_coulmn)

twelveth_coulmn<-sort(elventh_coulmn)

df<-data.frame(first_column,second_column,third_column,fourth_column,fifth_column,sixth_column,seventh_column,eight_column,ninth_coulmn,tenth_coulmn,elventh_coulmn,twelveth_coulmn)

df
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
list_col <- vector("list", length = 18)
list_col[[1]] <- c("^","G","A","T","T","A","C","A")
for (i in 2:18) {
  if (i %% 2 == 0) {
    list_col[[i]] <- sort(list_col[[i - 1]])
  } else {
    list_col[[i]] <- paste(list_col[[1]], list_col[[i - 1]])
  }
}

list_col |> 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  setNames(paste0("col", 1:18))
```

Answer (score 0):

We may create a condition in the `for` loop

```
df <- data.frame(first_column = c("^","G","A","T","T","A","C","A"))
df$second_column <- sort(df$first_column)
library(english)
or(i in 3:12) {   
  if(i %%2 != 0) {
      df[[i]] <- paste(df[[1]], df[[i-1]])
      
     
} else {
   df[[i]] <- sort(df[[i-1]])
    
    
}
names(df)[i] <- paste0(ordinal(i), "_column")

}
```

-output

```
> df
  first_column second_column third_column fourth_column fifth_column sixth_column seventh_column eighth_column ninth_column tenth_column eleventh_column
1            ^             ^          ^ ^           ^ ^        ^ ^ ^        ^ ^ ^        ^ ^ ^ ^       ^ ^ ^ ^    ^ ^ ^ ^ ^    ^ ^ ^ ^ ^     ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
2            G             A          G A           A A        G A A        A A G        G A A G       A A G A    G A A G A    A A G A A     G A A G A A
3            A             A          A A           A G        A A G        A G A        A A G A       A G A A    A A G A A    A G A A G     A A G A A G
4            T             A          T A           A T        T A T        A T C        T A T C       A T C T    T A T C T    A T C T A     T A T C T A
5            T             C          T C           C T        T C T        C T A        T C T A       C T A T    T C T A T    C T A T C     T C T A T C
6            A             G          A G           G A        A G A        G A A        A G A A       G A A G    A G A A G    G A A G A     A G A A G A
7            C             T          C T           T A        C T A        T A T        C T A T       T A T C    C T A T C    T A T C T     C T A T C T
8            A             T          A T           T C        A T C        T C T        A T C T       T C T A    A T C T A    T C T A T     A T C T A T
  twelfth_column
1    ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
2    A A G A A G
3    A G A A G A
4    A T C T A T
5    C T A T C T
6    G A A G A A
7    T A T C T A
8    T C T A T C
```